# BigQuery error in cp operation: Error processing job: Unexpected. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

bq cp  --headless -f    throwing  error  unexpected please try again. Job id is 42keys.com:epicplatform:bqjob_r13905a02_0000014ba64655a6_1.
This is running from python script using subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a BigQuery bug when multiple queries all append to a table and then the table is copied soon thereafter. Fix in progress.